# Starting Asp.Net MVC with VS2010 and MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am starting out with MVC on VS2010 RC, having done a lot with Web Forms previously, and have been working my way through various tutorials and guides for MVC 1.

My question is, is it worth buying an MVC 1 based book for use with MVC 2, or are they significantly different that that would make it confusing?

The reason I ask is because the MVC 2 books I am looking at are not due for publishing for another few months, and I haven't come across any major issues while doing the Nerd Dinner tutorial - however, I am coming to the edge of what tutorials can give me, and would like an indepth book on the subject.

Regards

Moo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best MVC1 book I have read is [Steven Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430210078). He is currently working on a new version which will be about MVC 2. The book is scheduled to be released in May 2010, but in the mean time you can have a look at [his video series about MVC 2 on Tekpub](http://www.tekpub.com/view/aspmvc/1). I haven't watched them myself, but if they're as good as his book, they'll be well worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the concepts will help, but there are lots of new functions in MVC2. Have you looked at Nerd-Dinner Codeplex site? (http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) that should have been updated to MVC2.

However there are alot of resources online - if i'm honest I find more detail online than in books, but thats the kind of person I am. What are you looking at, thats not in the online guides?

Comment: My main issue with regard to online guides et al is the lack of generic expansion on topics and concepts - guides tend to approach the learning from a very specific 'do this to achieve this result' method, while books (I tend to lean toward Apress in specific) generally approach it from a 'if you want to achieve this, here is the concept you need and this is what that concept does in depth'.  Online guides tend to hit a barrier very quickly when going from specific to generalised with regard to applying learned techniques to other situations, because they haven't covered the broader topic.